# How to live reload reactjs / webpack app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am just starting with webpack and I am having issues with the livereload. When I change some jsx code it refreshes the browser. However when this contains an error it looks like the localhost:3333 caches this same version. For example my component looks like this:

```
renders()
{
...
}

Error: Uncaught TypeError: inst.render is not a function
```

How can I fix this. This is what I call now: webpack-dev-server --watch

Comment: So what did you do to make it live reload?

Comment: Just call webpack-dev-server

Comment: So what is the way to do it then?